# difference of std::cell::Ref<T> and &T

Tags: rust

I need to implement a function up to specific signature using RefCell. The task is: given a list of nodes in binary tree at specific depth *d* derive the list of nodes on the next level *d+1*. I have a draft solution, but it wouldn't compile because of following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `node`
  --> src/lib.rs:31:5
   |
26 |         if let Some(child) = &node.left {
   |                               ---- `node` is borrowed here
...
31 |     new_level
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Why I expect my code to work: I only operate on references in the function `next_level`, therefore the fact that owned input vector of references will be dropped at the end of it's execution should not be a problem - the values I point to still live. I thought that the std::cell::Ref is equivalent of normal ref, except borrowing rules are enforced at runtime.

The same code works if I change input vec from `Vec<Ref<TreeNode>>` to `Vec<&TreeNode>`. Why? How the two differ?

Complete code:

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};
use std::rc::Rc;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}


fn next_level(lvl: Vec<Ref<TreeNode>>) -> Vec<Ref<TreeNode>> {
    let mut new_level = vec![];
    for node in lvl {
        if let Some(child) = &node.left {
            let rf = child.borrow();
            new_level.push(rf);
        }
    }
    new_level
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it errors with the `Ref` code is that the new `Ref` is *within* the input's `Ref` and thus *both* `Ref`s must exist for it to be valid. However, this function only returns one `Ref` and that's why it errors. Also, you can't return both `Ref`s at once since one depends on the other. The reason it works using the `&` code is that `&` doesn't require the original reference to still exist for it to exist, as the original reference doesn't need to do things like run code when it's destroyed as `Ref` does.

I would advise passing around `Vec<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>`s in this case:

```rust
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};
use std::rc::Rc;

// Definition for a binary tree node.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct TreeNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub left: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
    pub right: Option<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>,
}


fn next_level(lvl: Vec<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>>) -> Vec<Rc<RefCell<TreeNode>>> {
    let mut new_level = vec![];
    for node in lvl {
        if let Some(child) = &node.borrow().left {
            new_level.push(child.clone());
        }
    }
    new_level
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the `child.clone()` is a deep copy with all sub-nodes or is it just a copy of Rc?

Comment: It's just a copy of the Rc, so it's cheap.